# Can you use a database view created in MySQL in a model? Is it good or bad practice?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing and application in php/laravel and find I need a view built in MySQL in a number of places.  Should I create a model to access the view?  I've already created the migration and am using DB:table() to access it.  Is it considered good or bad practice?  Is this a non-issue?  Are there any special provisions I have to make to place a database view into a model?

Comment: If you just need the view for reporting purposes, it's a great idea. There are some performance / management concerns with using it in other situations, but it's not strictly a bad or good practice.  Simple example, if you have a User model, a view would be a terrible idea because it is read only and you presumably want to change a user.  If it was a UserReports model, a view could be a good idea.  On the other hand, you may want to keep the report logic close to the app using it.  Just depends on who wants to manage what.

Comment: It's used strictly for read only purposes, no updates.  It's used to create a "browse" screen.  The complex part is that it not only has joins but those joins have additional joins that aren't needed until you get to the blade, depending on the blade your in.  I would just like to make life easier (low maintenance) by moving it all into a model.

Comment: The next question is, do I place all the columns in the model's $guarded array to ensure is remains read only?